# Lagrange Polynomial Interpolation - Polynomyal Differences Depending Upon the Degree?

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

My question is simple:

Give the table:

|  x |0|2|4|6|
|f(x)|1|3|5|7|

Why when calculating Lagrange Polynomial Interpolation for:

|  x |0|2|
|f(x)|1|3|

P1(x) = x+1

And when calculating Lagrange Polynomial Interpolation for:

|  x |0|2|4|
|f(x)|1|3|5|

P2(x) = 1,5x^2 +1x + 1   ??

And when calculating Lagrange Polynomial Interpolation for:

|  x |0|2|4|6|
|f(x)|1|3|5|7|

P3(x) = -0,229166666...x^3 + 0,75x^2 + 0,2033333...x + 1 ??

My calculations for P2(x) and P3(x) are wrong??

If you calculate in "Lagrange Calculators" at Internet, if you give the points for some values of the table, or all (P3(X)), the result is always "x + 1".

Please help me...

Comment: Dear Moo, 

Example: At n=3:

| x |0|2|4| |f(x)|1|3|5|

L0(X) = (x^2)/8 - 6x/8 +1
L1(X) = 0,25x^2 + 1x
L2(X) = 0,125x^2 - 0,250x

P2(X)= 1*L0(X)+3*L1(X)+5*L2(X) = 1,5x^2 + 1x +1.

Any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You second result is wrong, you must obtain $P_2(X)=X+1$.

$$l_0(X)=\frac{X-2}{0-2} \frac{X-4}{0-4}=\frac{1}{8}(X-2)(X-4)$$
$$l_1(X)=\frac{X-0}{2-0} \frac{X-4}{2-4}=\frac{-1}{4}X(X-4)$$
$$l_2(X)=\frac{X-0}{4-0} \frac{X-2}{4-2}=\frac{1}{8}X(X-2)$$
$$P_2(X)=1l_0(X)+3l_1(X)+5l_2(X)=X^2(\frac{1}{8}-\frac{3}{4}+\frac{5}{8})+X(-\frac{2}{8}-\frac{4}{8}+\frac{12}{4}-\frac{10}{8})+\frac{8}{8}=X+1$$

For $P_3$ you also have $P_3(X)=X+1$.

Comment: Yes...I made tiny mistakes that end up spreading the wrong results. I have reviewed the calculations, and all P(X) resulted in X+1.

P1(X) = X+1
P2(X) = X+1
P3(X) = X+1

Generally, P(X) is always the same for all Pn(X), right?

Thank you very much, Jennifer.

Comment: I can't tell you if Pn will always be the same, it depends of your new values x and f(x). But if they follow the pattern f(x)=x+1, Pn will always be the same.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!